# Guarding Your Eyes In Public School

Tags: sin, tznius-modesty, see-sight-vision-blind, college-university-school

What would be some great ways for one to guard their eyes while attending public school with immodesty being everywhere?

Looking for sources please- thanks!

Comment: your answer might be here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38361/4794

Comment: Come at night - works 99.9%!

Comment: How is it different from say public transportation?

Comment: @AlBerko School is total immersion with a defined group of people, who you meet and interact with daily. As such, the temptations are much different than public transportation, which usually involves random encounters. Even if you take the same bus daily, with the same people, the interaction is much different than in a school setting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I curb my sexual desire?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16734/how-can-i-curb-my-sexual-desire)

Comment: Guarding your eyes at school is quite different in my opinion than guarding your eyes at let’s say a store or at the mall. For some reason it’s just harder. I think it’s because there’s so many people crowded in one area with insane immodesty. Not gonna say it’s impossible because nothing is, but it’s extremely hard.

Comment: @AlBerko  Any tips on how one can guard their eyes at school? It’s quite different than other scenarios. One would literally have to stare at the floor the whole time.

Answer (score 4):

I've attended an interesting lecture in my boys' school in Jerusalem (I think) and the (frum) lecturer presented a very interesting approach to what you ask.

This topic is actually overhyped in Judaism, with Rabbis artificially provoking people's (especially young ones) urges with talks on the severity of lust, actually causing the problem.

The solution, he claimed, would be taking this subject into proportions and adjusting the view to the current conditions. He gave an example of the hippie revolution - "free love" - that lasted a while, for as long as it was a novelty, but eventually, people lost interest in it.

Same here, one should stop focusing on this particular subject and focus on other, not less important aspects of the Jewish conduct - Kosher food, Tefilos, בין אדם לחבירו, honoring parents, studying Torah etc.

I'd add two practical points to that :

- some meditation will surely help - learning to keep unwanted thought out of mind.
- the Sages taught us - אתי עשב ודחי ללא תעשה - the positive Mitzvos overcome negative ones. So stop counting your failures and count your merits.

Comment: I agree with this one hundred percent.